# Can not add peer in local ethereum blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to add one node to my local ethereum , I am running the first node with :

```
geth --port 30303 --networkid 1234 --nodiscover --datadir ethereum/paradox  --rpc --rpcport 8545  --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000"  --allow-insecure-unlock --ethstats paradox:s3cr3t@localhost:3000  --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner"
```

and my Second node with :

```
  geth --datadir "$ethereum_home/sample" --nodiscover --networkid 1234 --port 30304
```

they both points to the same genesis block.

When i run command "addPeers" itt returns true but the It does not show peers when I run "admin.peer"

My genesis file:
`{ "config": { "chainId": 4224, "homesteadBlock": 0, "eip150Block": 0, "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "eip155Block": 0, "eip158Block": 0, "byzantiumBlock": 0, "constantinopleBlock": 0, "petersburgBlock": 0, "istanbulBlock": 0, "ethash": {} }, "nonce": "0x0", "timestamp": "0x5f350017", "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "gasLimit": "0x47b760", "difficulty": "0x80000", "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "alloc": { "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": { "balance": "0x1" }, "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ff": { "balance": "0x1" } }, "number": "0x0", "gasUsed": "0x0", "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" }`

[image]
The interesting thing is when I stop both node and restart again and then do "addPeers" it shows other node in peer array but just for a second and if I run command admin.peer it shows noting.

Answer (score 1):

You have port 30305 running in your lines for one node, and 30303 for another. Why have you tried addPeer with port 30304? Check the availability of the ports listed on the command line while running geth instances. And check correctly node key and port.

Comment: No actually I have multiple node runnning that screenshot was when I was connecting with the instance running on port 30305. I also tried on port 30304 but still noting.